# Why is checkbox in Datatable triggering CREATE action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Ajax Datatable in Rails, and a column with a Select_all checkbox.

```
<th class="check_box">
  <input type="checkbox" name="people-datatable-select_all" id="people-datatable-select_all" value="1" title="Tout cocher/Tout décocher" />
</th>
```

But when the user click on the select all, it briefly select all the rows, then trigger a reload of the table, how can I prevent the reload from happening, so I can collect all the checked boxes and trigger a custom action please?

My JS Script look as :

```
 $("#people-datatable-select_all").change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            $("input:checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked);
        } else {
            $(".input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
```

What is the best way to stop that reload please ?

Comment: The `if` condition seems superfluous won't  `$("input:checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked)` suffice? I think your issue is that you are actually re-targeting the same checkbox (e.g. `$("input:checkbox")` will pick up `$("#people-datatable-select_all")`) and  `change` may be firing again. Possibly consider a more specific selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your check all function is calling a datatable reload. You might try adding `table.ajax.reload( null, false );` in your JS script with table being the datatable variable.

https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()